# local inventory file is not including with the ansible config file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add a local inventory file, so here are my questions:

1. do I need to create `ansible.cfg` file locally or any text doc would suffice?
2. do we need to include the path and add inventory in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file?

This is how my config file looks like:

```
inventory      = /root/ansible/dev
hostfile       = /etc/ansible/hosts
library        = /usr/share/ansible
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 5
poll_interval  = 15
sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
transport      = smart
remote_port    = 22
```

this is how the local inventory file looks like

```
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible# cat dev
dev   dev~  
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible# cat dev
[control]
control ansible_connection=local
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible#
```

but for some reason it doesnt show me the local inventory file

```
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible# cat dev
dev   dev~  
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible# cat dev
[control]
control ansible_connection=local
root@user-OptiPlex-790:~/ansible#
```

Comment: What is that: "*do i need to create ansible.cfg file locally or any text doc would suffice?*" supposed to mean?

Comment: sorry i meant if the file name should end with <filename>.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is here:

> inventory      = /root/ansible/dev
>   hostfile       = /etc/ansible/hosts

`inventory` is the new name of `hostfile` parameter. [Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hostfile).
So you basically define your inventory file as `/root/ansible/dev` and the overwrite it as `/etc/ansible/hosts`.

If you want it to be `/root/ansible/dev` just remove the second line.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,Many thanks for the reply.But my question is i want the ansible environment to pick up hosts from both files.(/etc/ansible/hosts+ inventory file).how can i achieve that

Comment: @vig the only way to combine inventory files I know is to use a directory as inventory path so all files in that directory are loaded by Ansible. But I guess you cant merge files from different directories.

Comment: you could use a [dynamic inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#using-inventory-directories-and-multiple-inventory-sources)  that merges whatever you want.

Comment: @user2599522 sure thing! I meant using out of the box configuration.